# Find the right package for missing files in TeXlive

Tags: packages, texlive

Is there any way in TeXlive to find the correct package which contains the missing file? I have installed a minimal scheme (without recommended/additional fonts) and now I get this error:

```
The command name is c:\texlive\2015\bin\win32\mktexmf
name = ptmr7t, rootname = ptmr7t, pointsize =
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!
Cannot find ptmr7t.mf.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font OT1/ptm/m/n/10=ptmr7t at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not foun
d.
<to be read again>
                   relax
l.373 \normalfont
                  \selectfont
```

Installed packages are shown below.

[image]

Comment: The Adobe *Times* font is missing (or the URW clone thereof), says your .log file. As I don't heva TeX Live, I'm unsure, but they should be in `Recommended fonts` or `Additioanl fonts`

Comment: Yeah I can try that. But was looking for a general solution. In linux, yum and apt provide some utilities for finding the correct package for a file

Comment: Yes, and with MiKTeX, which I use, you can see the list of files in a given MiKTeX package.

Comment: Finding what files are in what packages is less useful than the reverse.

Comment: How do you get that nifty window with all the packages listed? I have just installed TeXlive and have not figured out what CLI command opens this window.

Comment: @HedleyFinger: You may want to check the installation guide at https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you made a live install, you should have texlive tools working on your console (however I had troubles with them on windows). To search packages upon keyword, try

```
tlmgr search --global --all beamer
```

To find a file flagged as missing try

```
tlmgr search --global --file ptmr7t.mf.
```

Without --global, texlive will search only your local database, where the file is obviously missing. 
Once the package found, you can install it

```
tlmgr install thispackage
```

If you cannot do it with the console, there is also a GUI interface. I am not familiar with it, but it is described in [texlive manager (tlmgr) doc](http://tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html).