# TeX Live 2018 not finding font Inconsolata

Tags: texlive-2018

I am installing Tex Live for the first time. I am able to generate PDFs for the basic LaTeX files `sample2e.tex`, `small2e.tex`, `testpage.tex`, and `nfssfont.tex`, mentioned [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-370003.4.7).

When I try to build a book from R using the code below I get this (very long) error:

```
>system("xelatex -interaction=batchmode r-packages ")
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
name = Inconsolata, rootname = Inconsolata, pointsize = 
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

kpathsea: Running mktexmf Inconsolata.mf

The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktexmf
Cannot find Inconsolata.mf.
name = Inconsolata, rootname = Inconsolata, pointsize = 
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

kpathsea: Running mktexmf Inconsolata.mf

The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktexmf
Cannot find Inconsolata.mf.
name = Inconsolata, rootname = Inconsolata, pointsize = 
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

kpathsea: Running mktexmf Inconsolata.mf

The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktexmf
Cannot find Inconsolata.mf.
name = Inconsolata/BI, rootname = Inconsolata/BI, pointsize = 
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

kpathsea: Running mktexmf Inconsolata/BI.mf

The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktexmf
Cannot find Inconsolata/BI.mf.
name = Inconsolata, rootname = Inconsolata, pointsize = 
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

kpathsea: Running mktexmf Inconsolata.mf

The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktexmf
Cannot find Inconsolata.mf.
name = Inconsolata/B, rootname = Inconsolata/B, pointsize = 
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

kpathsea: Running mktexmf Inconsolata/B.mf

The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktexmf
Cannot find Inconsolata/B.mf.
name = Inconsolata, rootname = Inconsolata, pointsize = 
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

kpathsea: Running mktexmf Inconsolata.mf

The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktexmf
Cannot find Inconsolata.mf.
name = Inconsolata/I, rootname = Inconsolata/I, pointsize = 
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

kpathsea: Running mktexmf Inconsolata/I.mf

The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktexmf
Cannot find Inconsolata/I.mf.
name = Inconsolata, rootname = Inconsolata, pointsize = 
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

kpathsea: Running mktexmf Inconsolata.mf

The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktexmf
Cannot find Inconsolata.mf.
name = Inconsolata, rootname = Inconsolata, pointsize = 
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

kpathsea: Running mktexmf Inconsolata.mf

The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktexmf
Cannot find Inconsolata.mf.
name = Inconsolata, rootname = Inconsolata, pointsize = 
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

kpathsea: Running mktexmf Inconsolata.mf

The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktexmf
Cannot find Inconsolata.mf.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm Inconsolata

The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktextfm
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm Inconsolata

The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktextfm

kpathsea: Running mktextfm Inconsolata

The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktextfm

kpathsea: Running mktextfm Inconsolata/BI

The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktextfm

kpathsea: Running mktextfm Inconsolata

The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktextfm

kpathsea: Running mktextfm Inconsolata/B

The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktextfm

kpathsea: Running mktextfm Inconsolata

The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktextfm

kpathsea: Running mktextfm Inconsolata/I

The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktextfm

kpathsea: Running mktextfm Inconsolata

The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktextfm

kpathsea: Running mktextfm Inconsolata

The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktextfm

kpathsea: Running mktextfm Inconsolata

The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktextfm
```

I think the relevant part of the error message is:

```
name = Inconsolata, rootname = Inconsolata, pointsize = 
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!
kpathsea: Running mktexmf Inconsolata.mf
The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktexmf
Cannot find Inconsolata.mf.
name = Inconsolata, rootname = Inconsolata, pointsize = 
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!
```

I've tried running the code suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274536/find-the-right-package-for-missing-files-in-texlive/274551), which seems to find `Inconsolata` on my computer:

```
C:\Users...>tlmgr search --global --all Inconsolata
  tlmgr.pl: package repository 
  http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet (not
  verified: gpg unavailable)
  inconsolata - A monospaced font, with support files for use with TeX
  inconsolata:
        texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/inconsolata/InconsolataN-Bold.otf
        texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/inconsolata/InconsolataN-Regular.otf
        texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/inconsolata/Inconsolatazi4-Bold.otf
        texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/inconsolata/Inconsolatazi4-Regular.otf
        texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/inconsolata/Inconsolata-zi4b.pfb
        texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/inconsolata/Inconsolata-zi4r.pfb
        texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/inconsolata/InconsolataN-Bold.pfb
        texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/inconsolata/InconsolataN-Regular.pfb
C:\Users...>tlmgr search --global --file Inconsolata.mf
  tlmgr.pl: package repository 
  http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet (not
  verified: gpg unavailable)
C:\Users...>tlmgr install tlmgr.pl
  tlmgr.pl: package repository 
  http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet (not
  verified: gpg unavailable)
  tlmgr.pl install: package tlmgr.pl not present in repository.
  tlmgr.pl: action install returned an error; continuing.
  tlmgr.pl: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

And when I run `tlmgr-gui.exe` it lists the `Inconsolata` package as already being installed. So why do I get the error `Cannot find Inconsolata.mf.'? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a inconsolata.fontspec in the package, which is used if you try to load the font by name. But it works for me on windows only correctly, if I call the font with a lowercase i, with uppercase I it breaks with your error message:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Inconsolata} %breaks
\setmainfont{inconsolata}  %works
\begin{document}
abc

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before starting I should list my environment info. This should apply to versions of R and latex in circulation as of the previous year. This is, of course, a linux-specific guide but with simple modifications, should port to other OS'es

uname -a
Linux First-Floor 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft #476-Microsoft Fri Nov 01 16:53:00 PST 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

latex -v
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.3

Before I continue, I should say that I found the following post extremely useful in helping to understand how mktexlsr or texhash finds the directory trees from the texlive configuration:

https://ipfs-sec.stackexchange.cloudflare-ipfs.com/tex/A/question/20160.html

Having read that page, we learn that my distro at home (windows subsystem linux, ubuntu has the distro in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist and the local tree
in /usr/local/share/texmf  while at work, CENTOS 7.4, from about two or three years ago, has distro in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist and the local tree
in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-local. That looks problematic because of course
local trees are supposed to be in /usr/local/share so they don't get 
written over by package updates, but so far so good. These are the steps I took
at home.

1. Find the main branch of your tex distribution. For my fairly recent texlive its /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist
2. As mentioned in the post linked above, find out where your local tree goes by
   looking at the texmf.cnf file in the web2c subfolder within your main distro 
   texmf root.

   ```
   cd /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c
   less texmf.cnf
   ```
3. It is there that we learn, in my case, that

   ```
   % Local additions to the distribution trees.
   TEXMFLOCAL = /usr/local/share/texmf
   ```
4. So this is where we start. If you don't have the following subdirectories, make them

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/texmf
   sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/texmf/doc
   sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/texmf/fonts
   sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/inconsolata
   ```
5. download the inconsolata-zi4.zip package

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   wget http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/inconsolata-zi4.zip
   unzip inconsolata-zi4.zip
   ```
6. As root, execute the following commands (the first is to become root). NOTE "MyName"
   is the name of your user home directory

   ```
   sudo su -
   cp ~/Downloads/inconsolata/doc /usr/local/share/texmf/doc
   cp -ru ~/Downloads/inconsolata/tex/* /usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/inconsolata
   dns="enc map opentype tfm type1"
   for d in $dns; do
     mkdir -p /usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/$d/inconsolata
     cp -ru /home/MyName/Downloads/inconsolata/$d/* /usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/$d/inconsolata
   done
   ```
7. Execute some of the commands in block "A" of the README file, being
   careful to customize the paths to your local texmf tree.

   ```
   sudo echo Map zi4.map >> /usr/local/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
   sudo mktexlsr
   sudo -H updmap-sys
   ```

This worked out great for me. Now R CMD check mypkg is able to build the manual.