# File `perpage.sty' not found. \MakePerPage

Tags: compilation-error, footmisc, texlive-2023, perpage

I'm using TeXLive 2023 on Windows. I have the `footmisc` package installed, and use it like so:

```
\usepackage[symbol,perpage]{footmisc}
```

well, during document compilation, I'm getting:

```
File `perpage.sty' not found. \MakePerPage
```

So, I thought maybe I'd try installing the `perpage` package - but there is no such package in TeXLive.

The line triggering the error is line 477 of `footmisc.sty`, which says:

```
\MakePerPage{footnote}
```

Still not much help. Now, I would assume that if `footmisc` needs `perpage.sty` - it should have either included that file as part of the installation - and yet it's missing. Why am I getting this error, and what can I do about it?

Notes:

- I know how to install TeXLive and individual TeXLive packages, please stop marking this as a duplicate of a question about doing that.

Comment: Do you have https://ctan.org/pkg/bigfoot installed?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: No, why? Will that resolve the problem?

Comment: `perpage` (which gets loaded by `footmisc` if you use the `perpage` option) is part of the `bigfoot` texlive package. So you need to have it installed.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: No, the issue here is the fact that footmisc depends on a file from bigfoot but doesn't require it.

Comment: `footmisc` does require the `perpage` package if you use the option of the same name: l. 476 of `footmisc`: `\RequirePackage{perpage}`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: But there is no perpage package in texlive - which is why you told me to install bigfoot. So, footmisc requires bigfoot.

Comment: the  `perpage` latex package is part of the `bigfoot` texlive package. A texlive package can contain several latex packages. Footmisc does not requite all of bigfoot, just the perpage latex package, but for convenience it is easier to install the whole bigfoot package.

Comment: (or install a complete texlive instead, this would also avoid problems with firewalls or outdated texlive versions as everything would already be installed)

Comment: "it should have installed it." Texlive doesn't normally do on the fly installation of missing packages.  The user has to install them.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: See my answer. If I installed footmisc, texlive should have installed everything footmisc relies on.

Comment: bigfoot is a soft dependency, not every footmisc user will need it.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: There's nothing soft about that, it's just a dependency.

Comment: It is soft, because it is only required if you use the `perpage` option

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Well, if you don't use footers at all in your document, maybe you don't really need any files. That doesn't matter. a dependency is a dependency and tlmgr should make sure it is satisfied.

Comment: If you think there is something wrong with how the package works, you should probably write the relevant author a message. Most people here are not responsible for how packages are coded, they only try to help others understand how the packages work.

Comment: @JasperHabicht: It's not the footmisc package itself - which works fine , it is just the missing dependency. But I will get in touch with the TeXLive people about it.

Comment: in a perfect world every dependency would be resolve automatically without you having to think about it. In the real world you sometime have to install a package manually. Why do you make such a fuss about it? The obvious solution when you get such an error is to install the package and go on with life.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Because you can't install a "perpage" package manually. If that was the problem, of course I'd just install it. The thing is, perpage.sty was hiding inside another TeXLive package.

Comment: Yes in a perfect world perpage.sty would be in the perpage package, in the real world packages sometimes have a different name. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/274551/2388 or the documentation of tlmgr how to find which package contains a file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: And that's why users who come up against these situations ask question on TeX.SX, and other people answer them. That being said - software distributions track dependencies well enough (e.g. npm, conan, Linux distributions etc.) - so why can't TeXLive track theirs? Anyway, the answer you linked to would probably have worked for me; and if my question had been closed as a duplicate of _that_ question, I wouldn't have complained.

Comment: @einpoklum just flag your question, mods and gold badge holders can add additional dupe targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of a TeXLive bug (which has, by now, been reported and fixed by Karl Berry; but apparently, the fix may have been backed out). Indeed, the dependency of `footmisc` on `perpage.sty` should have resulted either in `perpage.sty` being installed as part of `footmisc`, or alternatively, should have created a package dependency between `footmisc` and another package which offers `perpage.sty`.

As described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/274551/5640), you can search other packages for that file. This should result in:

```
bidi:
    texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/bidi-perpage.sty
bigfoot:
    texmf-dist/tex/latex/bigfoot/perpage.sty
lwarp:
    texmf-dist/tex/latex/lwarp/lwarp-perpage.sty
zref:
    texmf-dist/tex/latex/zref/zref-perpage.sty
```

The package we need is `bigfoot`. So, just [install it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016/5640), e.g. by using `tlmgr install bigfoot`) - and `footmisc` will now manage to find its missing file.

Thanks @UlrikeFischer for pointing me to the right way one should handle such situations.

Comment: Could you update this? The dependency was removed because it is only soft i.e. adding the dependency was determined to be incorrect and your original report determined not to be a bug after all. As it stands, your answer will convince people something is wrong if it doesn't work automatically. (But the information about how to satisfy the dependency is obviously useful. You just need to make clear this is something people need to do for themselves unless they install a more complete system.)

Comment: @cfr Updated, but it is a bug after all. "Soft", "hard", call it what you will - if you need perpage.sty to use footmisc features, then it being missing after installing footmisc is a bug, period. If I had the time I would take this up with the TeXLive people, but I did my duty reporting the bug and it's up to them to not be ridiculous about it.

Comment: There is no such thing as "optional dependencies" for packages. There are dependencies, and non-dependencies. A package may recommend other packages, and may even be able to do more in the presence of different files on the system - but packages are never built so as to depend on non-dependencies, and thus never crash, or fail to load due to a missing shared library, etc. And that's because everything they _depend_ on is present and working. footmisc _depends_ on perpage.sty being present, as it assumes its presence.

Comment: "footmisc only looks for perpage if the perpage option is enabled" <- that means, that you can't use footmisc without perpage.sty . For it to be usable, it should never assume perpage.sty exists. It could say "option perpage not supported, blah blah blah" and that's fine. What it can't do is just load it. That's a _dependency_, as opposed to a non-dependency. Soft, hard, call it whatever you like. When you install footmisc the way it is now, bigfoot, or the perpage file, must be installed.

Comment: "the option is disabled" <- it's not disabled, it just defaults to false. If it were disabled, I would get an error message about an unsupported/unrecognized option.

Comment: "that means, that you can't use footmisc without perpage.sty" -> but the thing is, you can use footmisc without the perpage package. Many users do that. Only the users who use the `perpage` option need to have the perpage package. If you are forcing users to install things which they might or might not need, why bother with partial installations at all? If you want everything on hand for all possible uses of latex, this would mean everybody would need a full installation.

Comment: "you can use footmisc without the perpage package" <- crashing only in some cases rather than always does not count as "can use".

Comment: The user has the ability to not use a special option and thus not causing crashes.

Comment: @cfr: I haven't asked for a file which can't be found; footmisc has. And it's a bug of TeXLive to not avoid this happening; because footmisc.sty assumes perpage.sty can be loaded.

Comment: @einpoklum I've tidied up and recommend you do the same.

Answer (score 2):

> Now, I would assume that if footmisc needs perpage.sty - it should have either included that file as part of the installation - and yet it's missing. Why am I getting this error, and what can I do about it?

The `footmisc` package only requires `perpage` under certain conditions and not by default. Thus `bigfoot` is a soft dependency of `footmisc`:

https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/tlpkg/tlpsrc/footmisc.tlpsrc?revision=69890&view=markup

As of Feb 2024, texlive only considers hard dependencies. They are either specified by the package maintainers or contributed by users, so they are also far from complete. The user will have to install soft dependencies themselves. See https://tug.org/texlive/pkgcontrib.html#deps for some more information about package dependencies.

*(rumours have it that some people work on a more automated way to deal with dependencies, so this situation might change in the future)*

Comment: I don't know about all that, but this was recognized as a bug and fixed. So either the dependency was hardened, or they started installing soft dependencies. At any rate, the user will _not_ have to install bigfoot to get perpage in footmisc.

Comment: The incorrect classification as hard dependency was removed in the mean time.